# Map ids from 2 tables and find duplicate records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a 2 tables and I want to find which id's are duplicate:

```
create table main_pairs(
   pair_id         integer,
   pair_full_name  text
)


create table second_pairs(
   pair_id         integer,
   pair_full_name  text
)
```

I want to be sured that I don't have into the both tables records for table columns `pair_id` as duplicate records.

How I can check this with SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just join two tables by `pair_id`, rows that don't have counterparts will be filtered out:

```
SELECT *
  FROM main_pairs m
  JOIN second_pairs s ON (s.pair_id = m.pair_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intersect` to find which `pair_id`s are duplicate between the two tables:

```
select pair_id from main_pairs
intersect
select pair_id from second_pairs;
```